# how to write a query to insert textbox value in database using textbox id

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables `TemplateField` and `OptionFieldValues`.

TemplateField

```
TemplateFieldId     FieldName   IsActive    DisplayOrder    FieldType

1                   Deprication         1           1        TEXT
2                   Cash out flow       1           2        Multivalue
3                   Cash                1           3        TEXT
4                   useful life         1           1        TEXT
```

OptionFieldValues

```
OptionFieldValuesId  TemplateFieldId OptionFieldValues      
1                           1                20%
```

In first table, i'm storing the field names and field type of the presentation layer. using MVC.

In second table, i want to insert the values of those corresponding field id when we press the save button.

how to write a insert code here?

Comment: On a perfectionism note, the field type values appear inconsistent in their capitalisation (TEXT, Text, MUltivalue), there are duplicated DisplayOrder values, and Specific is misspelled in OptionSpecficFieldId. I don't exactly understand what you're hoping to insert into that second table? Do you have all the data that you're hoping to insert, and some database connection/query functions at hand?

Comment: i changed the table now which u can understand well now . the first table  have field names and field type ( textbox, dropdownlist) and displayorder is to display fields names on presentation layer when page is load. the second table  is to save the data which typed in the those fields. but here i need to save the data corresponding the TemplateFieldId not with FieldNames

Comment: What is the data you're wanting to save? Exactly what datatypes/format? I don't know what tools/languages you're working with. It would seem that you'd simply want: `INSERT INTO OptionFieldValues (TemplateFieldId, OptionFieldValues) VALUES (x, y);` Or is the problem that you only have a `FieldName`, not a `TemplateFieldId`? `INSERT INTO OptionFieldValues (TemplateFieldId, OptionFieldValues) VALUES ((SELECT TemplateFieldId FROM Table1 WHERE FieldName = x), y);`